# Ordering columns in to_sql

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to specify the order of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax in the `.to_sql()` statement in pandas? For example:

```
summary_df.to_sql('action', con=self.avails_conn, if_exists='replace', index='id',
    column_order = ['id', 'name', ...]
)
```

How could I add in `column_order` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify column order in the df itself, which should keep for sql.

i.e:

```
summary_df[['id', 'name', ...]].to_sql()
```

Comment: You'll need to use a list of column names inside the `__getitem__` brackets (`summary_df[['id', 'name', ...]]` but this is probably the best way, yes.